# Mousdown equivalent for mobile

Tags: android, iphone, html5-audio

I am trying to get an audio sound to play on touch, but cannot get it working consistently, its working in stock and dolphin on android but its not working at all on ipad. I have tried on mousedown, onclick, touchstart, on touchstart. None of them are working

```
<canvas id="scratcher1" class="scratchMe" width="99px" height="89px" onmousedown="alert(down)" onclick="alert(click)" touchstart="alert(touch)" ontouchstart="alert(ontouch)"></canvas>
<canvas id="scratcher2" class="scratchMe" width="99px" height="89px" onmousedown="scratch.play()"></canvas>
```

This is what its at now, switched to alerts so I could try and work out which is working, as I said neither are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find an answer through this forum.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?65787-How-to-combine-eventhandlers-for-mouse-and-touchscreen-(e-g-iPad)

Similar situation there with iPad.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

(function(){
    var 
    first = document.getElementById('scratcher1'), 
    second = document.getElementById('scratcher2');
    third = document.getElementById('scratcher3');
    fourth = document.getElementById('scratcher4');
    fifth = document.getElementById('scratcher5');
    sixth = document.getElementById('scratcher6');
    seventh = document.getElementById('scratcher7');
    eighth = document.getElementById('scratcher8');

```
first.ontouchstart = second.ontouchstart = third.ontouchstart = fourth.ontouchstart = fifth.ontouchstart = sixth.ontouchstart = seventh.ontouchstart = eighth.ontouchstart = function () {
    scratch.play()
};
```

})();

Is what finally got it working.

Answer (score 0):

you can add event programatic to the canvas, with javascript init code:

```
document.getElementById("scratcher1").addEventListener("mousedown", alert, false);
```

it's suppose to work.
more about this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/AddingMouseandTouchControlstoCanvas/AddingMouseandTouchControlstoCanvas.html) under "Responding to Mouse and Touch Events on Canvas"

Answer (score 0):

All touch action provide the following touch action sequence:

ontouchstart
ontouchmove
ontouchend
onclick

only ontouchmove can be avoided, rest all are generated for the touch actions.

Please check against these. hope it helps